# Why did we use subtraction symbol to represent negative numbers

Tags: notation, arithmetic, real-numbers, math-history, integers

Why did we use subtraction symbol to represent negative numbers? We could have just used some other symbol to represent negative number such as

.5

.6

.11

And we can add these numbers, subtract these numbers

.5 + .6 = .11

.5 - .4 = .1

5 + .4 = 1

Comment: $(-x) = 0 - x.$

Comment: I suppose it’s nice that we can write things like $0 - 2 = -2$, rather than say $0 - 2 = !2$. (Here I’m using “$!2$” to denote the additive inverse of $2$.)

Comment: See [Negative number: History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_number#History) for sources.

Answer (score 2):

The notation fits nicely with the fact that adding a negative number is the same as subtracting the positive number.  Thus instead of writing

$$10 + (-2)$$

we can just as well write

$$10 - 2.$$

It's especially nice with more complicated algebraic expressions.  I like

$$y - 4(x+3) = y-4x-12$$

way better than

$$y + (-4)(x+3) = y + (-4)x + (-12).$$